# json_build_object in DQL

Tags: symfony, postgis, dql

Does anybody know how to write below query in **Symfony/Doctrine**?

```
SELECT json_build_object(
    'type',       'Feature',
    'id',         id,
    'geometry',   ST_AsGeoJSON(geom)::json,
    'properties', json_build_object(
        'name', building_name,
        'type', building_type,
        'area', ST_Area(geom)::numeric(10,2)
        )
    )
FROM geoepom.buildings WHERE id=1;
```

Query works perfect when I run it with **psql** or **phppgadmin**.

Answer (score 1):

You definitely should consider using this [bundle](https://github.com/creof/doctrine2-spatial). I've used it a lot and it allows you to do everything you want with spatial data and Doctrine (and its documentation is great).

BUT, json_build_object is specific to PostGres and so it's not supported in Doctrine (nor in the bundle I mentioned). For this particular case, you should [read this in SF doc](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/dbal.html#registering-custom-mapping-types) to create your own implementation through a custom Doctrine Type.
However, if all you want to do is to serialize your object to JSON after retrieving it from the database, you should have a look at [the serializer component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html) or [JMS Serializer](http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSSerializerBundle).

Short version would be "*Build you model through your entity, query through the ORM, and manage your data exposure through a Serializer*".

Answer (score 0):

I'm using 
https://github.com/jsor/doctrine-postgis
and couldn't do it either

Comment: So you should definitely consider creating your own Doctrine Type or (better option imho) serialize your hydrated object with your own logic with a Serializer.

Comment: At this stage is to much overwork despite I do not know how to do it.
Right now I just use queries to get ready GeoJson FeatureCollection.
Maybe in the future ...